# Who's using MFC's VERIFY Macro?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

To think ... there I have been happily programming in an MFC riddled environment for years, using ASSERT() whenever it seemed OK and just today I (was) stumbled upon the VERIFY Macro:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcatwy09%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

It's basically the same as ASSERT() except the expression will not be removed in release builds (the *check* will, but the *expression* will still be evaluated).

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define VERIFY(f)          ASSERT(f)
#else   // _DEBUG
#define VERIFY(f)          ((void)(f))
```

I can see a few uses for it, but I was wondering if others use it regularly in their code base and if anyone has seen any adverse side effects of using it.

cheers.

Comment: I think the better question is "Who's still using MFC?" :p

Comment: @tzaman - ;) ... MFC is Microsoft's only and official *C++* wrapper around the Windows API. If you do native Windows GUI apps you use MFC. (Or Qt, or wxWidgets, or gtkmm, or... :-) ) If you have an MFC app, you're stuck with it. Plus: I think VS itself is written in (based on) MFC.

Comment: Hm, ATL/WTL is already forgotten nowadays?

Comment: @Georg ... ATL is not forgotten :-) It does not deal with any GUI related stuff though (AFAIK) And we use MFC primarily for GUI + CString.

Comment: WTL is dead, and doesn't provide anywhere near the amount of functionality the MFC UI classes do. WTL was promising in 2004 (and I sunk a lot of time on it...) but it's not feasible to build modern products on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I used to do MFC programming, I used it all the time.

Basically everything which returns something that I'm normally too lazy to check the return from, but which Lint then whines at you about, I would wrap in a VERIFY.   (Calls like ::CloseHandle, for example)

There cannot be any adverse side effects to using it in a released product, because it's a no-op on a release build anyway.

Comment: Another question is if we should have return values in the program that we are 'too lazy to check'. ::CloseHandle is a good example though.

Answer (score 2):

In my first programming gig, 15 years ago, I managed to speed up an existing project quite a lot. They had tons of `ASSERT`s in their code, but relied on the side effects. That meant they could only build debug builds, and their program would stop working in release mode. I just replaced all the `ASSERT`s by `VERIFY`s.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have code like this:

```
  ...
  const int optional_return_value = AnyOldFunctionOrMethod(params);
  ASSERT(optional_return_value == 42);
}
```

This will give `warning C4189: 'optional_return_value' : local variable is initialized but not referenced` in the release build.

The VERIFY Macro can avoid this, either by doing the function call + check on one line in the VERIFY macro (like [Will suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317646/whos-using-mfcs-verify-macro/3322670#3322670)) or by just using VERIFY instead of ASSERT in the check line.

Comment: The warning C4189 might not pop up during a release build.

Comment: @Alexandre - was is "might not" supposed to mean?

Comment: Martin - With my setup, VS2010, I had to use level 4 warnings reporting and build in debug mode for these to show up. They didnt show up in release or level 3 or lower. Perhaps there are other ways to do things though, and other compilers probably have different default values.